# Place a separate subproject in the Nuxt 3 project

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Can I place a separate subproject in the `Nuxt 3` project that is not handled by `Nuxt`? This is a folder with several `html` files, `js` + `jquery`, `css` and `images` - a regular `html` page. It should not be handled by `Nuxt` and `Vue`. How do I do this correctly? I put such a folder in static:

```
/static/html/page/index.html
```

But when trying to access as

```
/html/page/index.html
```

I get a Nuxt 404 error in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the public folder for that. If I am not mistaken the static has been named public in Nuxt 3.

Here is the public folder structure.

```js
/*
  ~/public
    -html
    -page
      -index.html
      -script.js
      -style.css
*/
```

Following the structured folder, you will be able to see the content of the `index.html` by going to this path `/html/page/index.html` or `/html/page/`

Adding styles and script inside the `index.html` example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/html/page/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Hello World
    </div>
    <script src="/html/page/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For the jQuery, you can use the CDN or download it and place it inside the public folder, same thing for the images.

Tested and it works! Hope that helps